# Glengarry Glen Ross movie quote meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

> *Blake:* That watch costs more than your car. I made $970,000 last year. How much you make? You see pal, that's who I am, and you're nothing. Nice guy? I don't give a shit. Good father? Fuck you! Go home and play with your kids. You wanna work here—close! You think this is abuse? You think this is abuse, you cocksucker? You can't take this, how can you take the abuse you get on a sit? You don't like it, leave.

In the above dialog, I don't understand what he means saying " if you wanna work here, close". What does close mean here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to IMDb, it's a movie about "An examination of the machinations behind the scenes at a real estate office." Blake and the other who he was talking to seem to sell real estate.

So, I believe that this *"close"* means "close a sale" or "close a deal".

> **[close](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/close)**
>   [verb] 8. [transitive] [business] to successfully complete the arrangements for a business deal
>   *He had to lower the price to close the sale.*

Answer (score 5):

I'll expand a bit on Damkerng's answer.  To "close" a sale means to get the customer to agree to buy what you're selling. Salespeople always talk about "closing" as the most important part of the sale (If you can't close, you can't sell, if you can close, you can sell).  In this particular movie (one of my favorites), the salespeople in this office are not doing well, and Blake has come in to "light a fire under them".  Presumably, they are failing to close enough of their "sits", or sales presentations.

The Alec Baldwin character (Blake) is saying that if you want to keep working here, you have to make sales, or "close".  Then he's asking how they think they can take the abuse that they will get from their customers ("the abuse you get on a sit") if they think he's being abusive now.

Comment: "As you all know, first prize is Cadillac Eldorado. Anybody wanna see second prize? Second prize's a set of steak knives. Third prize is you're fired. Do you get the picture? Are you laughing now?"  :)

Comment: Yah, I liked this quote too :D